# Test indexes on heavily-used table

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

While attempting to improve performance on a stored procedure, the execution plan reported some missing indexes (obvious wins). I see awful indexes on the table now - some repeated, some overlaps, some missing columns. I expect to drop some indexes entirely, update / consolidate others, and I *might* get to add one or two new ones (though I doubt it).

I've tuned indexes in the past, but on tables with relatively few sp's. This table has been identified as a problem but nobody's clear how to effectively test **hundreds** of dependent sp's. I believe I'll have to run every stored procedure, repeatedly, both before and after indexing, to demonstrate that any change is useful.

I've seen load-testing tools, and that inspired my first plan of attack. Is there an open-source tool that analyses the code / table and provides meaningful parameters, then executes hundreds of sp's in independent loops, multi-threaded? I hope not to have to hand-curate the parameter values. The server is rebooted weekly so historical patterns take a while to collect.

Second, is this the best approach? I've tuned indexes where only a few stored procedures were impacted, never anything at this scope - is there a better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: The suggested indexes are most likely (given what you said) only going to improve one sp - pretty unlikely it will degrade performance of any of the others. So you only need to test the one which flagged up the missing indexes.

Comment: This table gets tens of thousands of records each day, looks to be 50/50 "after hours" and "during hours". 99% is automated. Not too worried about inserts. I'm mostly interested in SELECTS. I intend to remove / change a lot of indexes, but have to be able to demonstrate improvements across ALL sp's.

Comment: No index will improve all SPs unless you have identical queries in each one. An index targets only a query for which the where clause can make use of it. Performance tuning is not something you apply as a blanket change, its typically targeted to a specific query (or set of similar queries).

Comment: There are unfortunately few good tools for this kind of thing. Your best bet is to use tools like `sp_BlitzIndex` and `sp_BlitzCache` on your plan cache to find poor performing queries after having made changes. Also you are probably going to have to look through the plan cache yourself and/or run a XEvent trace to find out what are the common queries, then look at common access patterns for those queries. For example: do they all begin with a unique lookup on one table then join that to others? Are they primarily OLTP with small lookup queries? Are they primarily big analytical queries? Etc.

Comment: @Charlieface would you please make your reply an answer, so I can accept it?